# How to do a deployment pipeline with Maven

Tags: java, maven, teamcity, continuous-deployment

We want to accelerate our build pipeline for a multi-module Java web application, which roughly consists of

- compile/code analysis
- unit tests
- integration tests
- GUI tests

At the moment each of these build steps starts from scratch, compiling and building again and again, which costs time and means that we do not deploy the actual files to production that have gone through the tests. Is it possible to get Maven to not recompile everything on subsequent steps but instead run the tests against the previously compiled classes?

We are using Maven3 to manage our dependencies and Teamcity as a build server (7 at the moment, planning to upgrade to 8 soon). I have tried to set up a build chain, doing a

```
mvn clean install
```

on the first step and then exporting all the **/target/* folders to the following builds. Then ideally I would only do a

```
mvn test
mvn integration-test
```

Unfortunately I have not been able to persuade Maven to do this properly. Either it compiles the classes again or produces errors.

Has anyone successfully done this kind of setup and has any pointers for me? Is this possible with Maven and is this even the right way to do things?

Comment: It is very much possible and very easy. What kind of errors does it produce? Do you checkout the builds on your build server? Calling mvn test shouldn't trigger a recompile, so I can't be sure where you are going wrong unless you give us more info, maybe some stack trace of the mvb builds...etc

Comment: i chckout the sources on the subsequent builds and copy over the target directories from the compile build.

Comment: Yes, sounds correct. I don't believe that on default mvn config calling only mvn test recompiles the modules, but on the other hand, calling mvn test is not required. Just using mvn clean install, should trigger your tests by default as well. Then you can run your integration and whatever other tests using the stuff that is in the target folders.